# JSON console show the object, but gives undefined property error after with Vue.js

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, database, vue.js

Ok so firstly I'm grabbing the json object from the DB which is in this format...

```
{
    "position": "slider",
    "size": "large",
    "type": "slider",
    "params":[{
        "id": "10", 
        "title": "testfea",
        "extension": "jpg",
        "type": "image",
        "path": "\/image\/1.jpg"        
    }]    
}
```

I do some filtering using grep...

```
 // get all the large widgets
    var largeWidgets = $.grep($widgetsData, function(e){
        var farr = $.parseJSON(e.params);
        return farr.size == 'large';
    });

    // get all the widgets where the position equals the live one
    var filteredByPos = $.grep(largeWidgets, function(e){
        var farr = $.parseJSON(e.params);
        return farr.position == that.position;
    });
```

I'm using vue.js so I assign it to the data object...

```
this.fullWidget = filteredByPos;
var json = fullWidget[0].params;
console.log(json.params[0]);
```

so firstly it logs the Object, but then when I try and access properties it gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

at this position

```
var json = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(that.fullWidget[0].params));
```

specifically the [index].property

```
that.fullWidget[0].params
```

Comment: Is `arrayFromDB` an object? Your code takes that value, turns it in to JSON, then deserialises it back to an object again...? In theory you can bypass all of that and just use `var fullWidget = arrayFromDB; console.log(fullWidget.params[0])`

Comment: hang on let me re edit, yes you are right the object is saved as an object in the DB. but for some reason it is outputting it as an array...

Comment: Ok so that.fullWidget is assigned as an array. but I don't push it. I just assign the DB result to the variable. which should just make it a json object... but for some reason it is saving as variable

Answer (score 1):

Either because `fullWidget` is not an array (or empty array), or because you're using `fullWidget` instead of `this.fullWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

because fullWidget is not an array just an object . try with fullWidget.params